# If $f$ is a linear function with positive slope. $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

pf. Let x,y $\in$ $\mathbb R$. Suppose $x < y$. Then, $f(x)=2x$ and $f(y)=2y$. Then $2x<2y$. Therefore $f(x)< f(y)$.

I just made $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ those because those are both linear functions with positive slopes.

Is this an acceptable proof ?

Comment: No, this is not a formal proof. This is merely an example.

Comment: @FelicioGrande Ok, how do I make this a formal proof?

Comment: You have to generalize $f$, $f$ cannot be a set function, you must show this is true for all $f$ that meet the criteria

Comment: @FelicioGrande Ok, what is the first step in showing this is a true statement for all f.

Comment: Well based on the conditions that you gave $f$, i.e. $f$ is linear and has positive slope, then use that fact to create a proof to show that $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb R$

Comment: What class is this for? An analysis class or calculus?

Comment: @FelicioGrande Analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

General form of linear function is $f(x)=ax+b$. Slope is positive, so $a>0$.

Now, you have to show that if $x_1<x_2$, then $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.

Start with $f(x_1)$, conclude why $ax_1<ax_2$ and finish with $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.